# Linker Error Building GDAL VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, gdal

I'm trying to build GDAL using the 64-bit developer command prompt for VS2017.  When I try to run the nmake command on the makefile, I get the following fatal error:

```
odbccp32.lib(dllload.obj) : error LNK 2019: unresolved external symbol _vsnwprintf_s
referenced in function StringCchPrintfW
gdal202.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266542/linker-error-building-gdal) that addresses the exact same issue, but on MSVC 2015.  I checked the nmake.opt file, and it already had the MSVC 2015 solution implemented.  Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `nmake` like

```
nmake /f makefile.vc devinstall MSVC_VER=1900
```